# celery - same parameters, multiple invocations

Tags: python, celery

Either I haven't understood how [Celery](http://celeryproject.org) works, or it works strange for me.

I have following daemon.py module:

from celery.task import task

```py
import time


@task
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(x + y)
    return "x+y=%s" % (x + y)
```

launched celeryd with command:

```py
$ celeryd -I daemon -l DEBUG
```

And in separate python console, I did the following:

```py
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53)
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from daemon import add
>>> r = add.delay(100,20)
>>> r
<AsyncResult: 016a6eac-333c-4606-9f3c-ea3b38dac0ea>
```

And now, I thought that when I repeat add.delay(100,20), then it won't invoke another add function, but will return me AsyncResult of currently working daemon.add. However:

```py
 >>> r2 = add.delay(100,20)
 >>> r2.ready()
 False
 >>> r.ready()
 True
```

So apparently r2 is *different* invocation and *different* result than r.

Do I do something wrong? Or I don't understand how celery should be used?

Python 2.7, Celery 2.4.5, Celery configuration:

```py
BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
REDIS_HOST = "localhost"
```

Comment: Why would it return the previous async result? What made you think that?

Comment: http://www.celeryproject.org/tutorials/first-steps-with-celery/ made me think that, but seems that I misunderstood. 

So, how can I get result of 10 minutes task I started at eg. previous web run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke a function like this:

```
>>> from daemon import add
>>> r = add.delay(100,20)
>>> r
<AsyncResult: 016a6eac-333c-4606-9f3c-ea3b38dac0ea>
```

`r` is an [AsyncResult](http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult) object that lets you retrieve the result of the task. You can call the [get](http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.BaseAsyncResult.get) method to block until the task has finished and return the result. You can also periodically call [ready](http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.BaseAsyncResult.ready) if you want to check if the task has finished yet without blocking.

If you want to check the result of a task and you no longer have a reference to the `AsyncResult` object, you can look it up by its task ID as shown [here](http://ask.github.com/celery/faq.html#results):

```
>>> from daemon import add
>>> r = add.AsyncResult('016a6eac-333c-4606-9f3c-ea3b38dac0ea')
>>> r.get()
```